# No se ejecuta el evento al ser elementos dinámicos, ¿Como delegar eventos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este codigo insertado manualmente pero remplazando oraDuration2 por oraDuration1 y así con los demás.

```
$('#addProgr').append(`
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text">Duration</label>
   </div>
        <input type='time' class='custom-select col-4' id='oraDuration2' name='oraDuration2'>

   <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Ora Inizio</span>
        </div>
        <input type="time" id="inizio2" class="form-control" name="inizio2" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Ora Fine</span>
        </div>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="fine2" name="fine2" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>
   </div>
`);
```

A la hora de calcularme la hora fine, cuando estoy en el primero, me lo calcula sin problema. Cuando pasa a éste, al estar añadido dinamicamente, no me lo calcula de ninguna de las dos maneras:

```
$("input[name=oraDuration2], input[name=inizio2]").change(function() {
      let inizio2 = $('input[name=inizio2]').val();
      let duration2 = $("input[name=oraDuration2]").val();

      if(inizio2 != "" && duration2 != ""){

        let durationH2 = duration2.substr(0, 2);

        let durationM2 = duration2.substr(3, 2);

        let hours2 = moment.utc(inizio2,'HH:mm').add(durationH2,'hour').format('HH:mm');

        let fine2 = moment.utc(hours2,'HH:mm').add(durationM2,'minutes').format('HH:mm');

        $("input[name=fine2]").val(fine2);

      }

    });
```

```
    $("#oraDuration2, #inizio2").change(function() {
      let inizio2 = $('#inizio2').val();
      let duration2 = $("#oraDuration2").val();

      if(inizio2 != "" && duration2 != ""){

        let durationH2 = duration2.substr(0, 2);

        let durationM2 = duration2.substr(3, 2);

        let hours2 = moment.utc(inizio2,'HH:mm').add(durationH2,'hour').format('HH:mm');

        let fine2 = moment.utc(hours2,'HH:mm').add(durationM2,'minutes').format('HH:mm');

        $("#fine2").val(fine2);

      }

    });
```

En cambio con el oraDuration1, inizio1,....(estructura insertada manualmente) no me da problemas

*(Pone ora porque esta en italiano)*

Comment: ¿Has probado con: `$(document).on('change', 'input[name=oraDuration2] ,input[name=inizio2]', function(e) {...});`? Es la forma de delegar eventos en elementos creados dinamicamente.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, va perfectamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para delegar eventos en un elemento creado dinámicamente (que aun no existe en el `DOM`) puedes usar: **[.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> `$(document).on([eventos], [selectores], [data], [handler]);`

A lo que en tu ejemplo sería:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=oraDuration2] ,input[name=inizio2]', function() {...});
```

en caso de tener que pasar parámetros al `handler`:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=oraDuration2] ,input[name=inizio2]', {param: "value"}, miFuncion);
```

Ya que no se podría hacer `miFuncion(param)` por que se ejecutaría directamente.

---

Si se quiere delegar varios eventos y controlar que eventos se ha ejecutado en la siguiente pregunta se puede ver:

[¿Cómo puedo delegar múltiples eventos a un elemento en el DOM?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266148/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-delegar-m%C3%BAltiples-eventos-a-un-elemento-en-el-dom)