# Mostrar maskinput cuando añado una nueva fila

Tags: php, html, jquery

Buenas tengo un javascript en el cual añado filas para ir añadiendo más datos si lo necesito, en este caso son medidas y sus precios.

El Javascript de mskinput es este:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dinero").inputmask('currency', {
            allowMinus: false,
            suffix: ' €',
            groupSeparator: ' ',
            radixPoint: ',',
            prefix: '',
            rightAlign: false,
            removeMaskOnSubmit: true,
            groupSeparator: '.', 
            digits: 2, 
            digitsOptional: false, 
            placeholder: '0',
            max: $(this).data('max')
        });
      });
```

Cuando doy al botón de añadir fila:

```
        var MaxFilas       = 10; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
        var Medidas   = $("#Medidas"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
        var AddMedida       = $("#AddMedida"); //Add button ID
        
        var d = Medidas.length; //initlal text box count
        var contador=1; //to keep track of text box added
        var d = $("#cantidadMedidas").attr('data-medidas'); // Cantidad actual de medidas del producto
        //on add input button click
        $(AddMedida).click(function (e) {
                //max input box allowed
                if(d <= MaxFilas) {
                    contador++; //text box added ncrement
                    //add input box
                    $(Medidas).append('<div class="row" style="position:relative;">\
                        <div class="col-6">\
                            <div style="position:relative;">\
                                <span class="simboloMedida">Medida</span>\
                                <input type="text" name="medida[]" id="medida_'+ contador +'" value="" class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2"/>\
                            </div> \
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-3">\
                            <div style="position:relative;">\
                                <input type="text" name="precioMedida[]" id="medida_'+ contador +'" value="" class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2 dinero"/>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-3">\
                            <div style="position:relative;">\
                                <input type="text" name="precioAntes[]" id="medida_'+ contador +'" value=" " class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2 dinero" required>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <a href="#" class="removeMedida"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a>\
                    </div>');
                    d++; //text box increment
                    
                    $("#AddMoreMedida").show();
                    
                    $('AddMedida').html("Add field");
                    
                    // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
                    if(d == 10) {
                        $("#AddMoreMedida").hide();
                            $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
                    }
                }
                return false;
        });
```

El inputmask lo tengo que se active cuando es un input con las clase `dinero`, en un input que no lo cargo con javascript me funciona, pero al añadir una fila nueva no me carga el maskinput. Alguna idea?

Comment: Necesitas delegar el evento: [¿Cómo puedo delegar múltiples eventos a un elemento en el DOM?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266148/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-delegar-m%c3%baltiples-eventos-a-un-elemento-en-el-dom)

Comment: Hola @Triby pero eso ya lo estoy haciendo, el problema que me imprime nuevos inputs con la clase `dinero` pero no se activa el maskinput

Comment: No, estás asignando directamente el evento a los elementos actuales con `$('.clase').evento(...);` y debes asignarlo más o menos así: `$(document).on('evento', '.clase', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: Puede ayudarme a entenderlo con una demostración di mi código en la respuesta? no entiendo bien que tengo que hacer @Triby

Comment: Lo que encontré acerca de _inputmask_ es muy antiguo, ¿puedes proporcionar el enlace donde lo descargaste? Ahí podría haber documentación al respecto.